# GCC C++11 Debug builds, Release fails

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, release, eigen3

I have a project I've been working for some time, always in debug.
Today I tried building a release, and it fails to compile throwing some very weird errors.
While the debug compiles without any warnings, release throws:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

Both CMake builds have c++11 enabled:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -std=gnu++11 -Wall -g")
set(CMAKE_CSS_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -std=gnu++11 -Wall")
```

How can I track What is causing the compilation errors in Release?

**EDIT** I am using Cmake 2.8 and have tried to compile with gcc-4.6.3 and 4.7.2 and both have the same problem.

**EDIT#2** Problem persists when using -std=c++0x instead of c++11.

**EDIT#3** Downgrading to g++4.6 did not do much help. The error now simply changed to:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2:etc...
```

**EDIT#4** I have removed `<thread>` which first caused problems. Then it was `<mutex>` and `<atomic>`. Now it is any piece of code that uses `std::shared_ptr<Blah>`.
It seems to me as if Release does not want to compile with C++11 at all. Is this on purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet the problem comes from this line:

```
set(CMAKE_CSS_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -std=gnu++11 -Wall")
```

Look, you set the variable `CMAKE_CSS_FLAGS_RELEASE`. Chances are you just wanted to set the variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` instead. That would explain why your c++11 is not enabled in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem by simply removing the CXX_FLAG, and using CMake's add definitions:

```
add_definitions("-std=gnu++11")
```

I do not know why this made it work, and why debug worked but release didn't, but it made a big difference.